# Immutable objects reference in wrapper-objects

Tags: java, reference, copy, immutability

Imagine the following scenario. All objects of type `T` are copyable. There are wrapper-objects that may contain references to many objects of type `T` or any extending class of `T`. Now all objects are contained in a state, and when any wrapper-object is used to modify said state, the state is copied beforehand. The problem is that the wrapper-objects point to the original states objects instead of the objects in the copied state thus making any modifications in regards to the objects contained in the wrapper-objects modify the original state instead of the copied state.

Is there any simple way to overcome this?

Example:

```
class A extends T {
  private int value;

  public A(int value) {
     this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
     return value;
  }

  public void setValue(int toSet) {
     this.value = toSet;
  }

  @Override
  public A copy() {
     return A(this.value); //Imagine deep-copy stuff here
  }
}
```

Now imagine a `State` that has a list of those `A`:

```
class Modification {
    A toModify;
    int toSet;
}

class State {
     List<A> objs = ...; // Some A's
     private State(State otherState) {
        //Deep-copy is done here...
        //Copy all A's that are contained in this state too
     }

     public State applyAModification(Modification mod) {
          State copy = new State(this);
          //now I want to modify the A that was referenced in mod
          //not the original, but the copy in the copied state
          return copy;
     }
}
```

Update: May someone point me into a direction or point on some keywords I may search for ? This question seems to be very specific, but even after trying to solve this problem for many hours there seems to be no real solution.

EDIT: Excuse all the typos, duh

Comment: Can you please provide a concise working program that illustrates your concern?  It's hard to understand and visualize the concepts with text only.

Comment: The objects are already deep-copied, but the references in the wrapper-objects still point to the original data, as they were constructed for objects in a specific state. This means that copying a state makes all coresponding wrapper-objects of the original state not appliable to the copy.

Comment: A concise -> working <- example seems undoable, i provided a skeleton

Comment: `The objects are already deep-copied, but the references in the wrapper-objects still point to the original data, as they were constructed for objects in a specific state.` That seems contradictory to me.  Deep copy shouldn't preserve references to original objects.

Comment: So how would that work in Java, how am I copying an object and replace all  all references to it with the new object, without some really ugly code? Is there any pattern or is my whole concept flawed?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to maintain versions of the class A or any subclasses inside it, rather than creating copies from outside. For example:

```
class A extends T {
    List<A> versions = new ArrayList();
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        versions.add(createCopy());
        this.value = value;
    }

    public A createCopy() {
        return deepCopycopyOfA;
    }
}
```

So in the end you are still dealing wih only 1 reference to A.
It will also encapsulate the complexity of creating copies on every mutation inside the respective class.

Comment: This will take up excess memory because managing when to remove a reference from the list is non-trivial, identifying the right A seems hard too.